# Where to store application data (non-user specific) on Linux

Tags: java, linux

In my [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)-based Java application I am developing a bundle to provide the rest of the system with access to the file system.  In addition to providing access to the user home directory, I also wish to provide access to a non-user specific area.  Exactly what this area will be used for is as yet undetermined, but it will not be for preferences (handled by a different bundle), however it may be used to store data that could change at runtime.

I intend on using the following directories for this purpose:

- [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) and [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7): “\ProgramData”.
- [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP): “\Documents and Settings\All Users“.
- [Mac OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X): “/Library/Application Support”.

Where is a sensible equivalent in Linux and how do I get a handle on it from my Java code?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what type of data you're storing? Is it data that's static (config files, static information, etc.) or is it data that's changed at runtime? I've answered below under the assumption of the latter, but after re-reading your question I'm not entirely sure what you're after.

Comment: I have reworded the question to (hopefully) clarify the situation somewhat.

Comment: Similar question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/whats-the-most-appropriate-directory-where-to-place-files-shared-between-users .

Comment: Similar question - https://superuser.com/questions/635289/what-is-the-recommended-directory-to-store-website-content .

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data you're planning on storing. This answer is under the premise that you're storing and modifying data at run time.

Contrary to what others have suggested, I would recommend against using `/usr/share` for storage. From the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREARCHITECTUREINDEPENDENTDATA):

> The /usr/share hierarchy is for all
> read-only architecture independent
> data files.

As you're modifying data, this goes against the read-only nature of the `/usr` subsystem.

A seemingly better place to store your application state data would be `/var`, or more specifically, `/var/lib`. This also comes from the [Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY). You could create a `/var/lib/myapp`, or if you're also using things like lock files or logs, you could leverage `/var/lock` or `/var/log`.

Have a deeper look at the standard as a whole (linked to above)—you might find a place that fits what you want to do even better.

[Like Steve K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510104/where-to-store-application-data-non-user-specific-on-linux/1510182#1510182), I would also recommend using the Preferences API for application preference data.

Comment: Writing program data to `/var` usually requires superuser privileges. What to do if the app is running as user?

Comment: @MathiasKunter - If the app is running as a specific user, you should set up the appropriate `/var/...` directories (e.g. `/var/log/my-app/`, `/var/lib/my-app/`, etc.) to give read/write access to that user or its group. Alternatively, if it's an actual human user you're talking about, you could consider using their home directory (e.g. `~/.my-app/...`).

Comment: If an app is running as an ACTUAL user, the data should be stored under that users  $HOME. If it is a system user, the install (as root or similar) should give that user ownership of its files and directories under /var, and add the user to any groups needed for access to additional devices/directories/files.

Comment: I guess the official FHS is now found [here](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)?

Comment: Storing in home programatically can be nightmarish as it is not an absolute path

Comment: What if I want store a database file (sqlite) - it hardly fits lib.. Is it?

Comment: @BoppityBop, looking through my /var/lib I find several (pretty known) tools that place their database files there. For example fail2ban

Comment: If there are unscrupulous developers who put their dbs in a lib (which is library - static file eg dlls) it's their problem. I would not do it

Comment: @BoppityBop `/var/lib` is for "variable state information", not static library files.

Answer (score 64):

It depends.

- Global configuration → */etc/appname*
- Read-only, independent of machine architecture → */usr/share/appname*
- Read-only, machine specific → */usr/lib/appname*
- Read-write → */var/lib/appname*

There isn't any guarantee for completeness. Please
check the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: How about log files? `/var/log/appname` maybe?

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using Java, look at the [Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/preferences/index.html).

From the introduction:

> Applications require preference and configuration data to adapt to the needs of different users and environments. The java.util.prefs package provides a way for applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data. The data is stored persistently in an implementation-dependent backing store. There are two separate trees of preference nodes, one for user preferences and one for system preferences

I'd let the built-in API do the work.

Comment: Thanks. We will be implementing a preferences service also (OSGi based), however also need access to the file system for other purposes.

Comment: The Linux implementation of the Preferences API does use the file system.  Not sure why it wouldn't suite your needs - can you expand on it more?  You can also create your own backing store for the preferences - if you want to take things that far.

Answer (score 6):

The [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/) (previously known as the X Desktop Group) project has defined some standards for this in the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/).

In your case, I'd have a look at `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`:

> `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for data files in addition to the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` base directory. The directories in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` should be seperated with a colon ':'.
>
> If `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is either not set or empty, a value equal to `/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/` should be used.

I warmly suggest to read the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Comment: On GNU Linux, [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/) are usually followed. There is probably a lot of overlap between GNU and XDG. Regarding the XDG directories, they don't seem to make accommodations for non-user-specific runtime data that is often stored somewhere in `/var`.

Answer (score 2):

In the */usr/share* or */usr/local/share* folders.

Answer (score 2):

According to *[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)*
(which seems to be updated and correct as of July 2015)...

> Assuming that the datafiles are understood to not meet the requirements of `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` then `/usr/local/share/theApp` or `/usr/local/theApp`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is non-user-specific, you can probably store it under */usr/share/appname*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the System.getProperty("user.home") to get the users home, so it's more platform independent.

Comment: I will be using that when I need access to the user's home, however my question is related to the non-user specific area (which can be obtained using System.getenv("ALLUSERSPROFILE") on Windows, but this does not work on Linux).

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I misunderstood what you were after. The Properties as suggested earlier has support for all users. I know in Windows it stores it in the registry, not sure where it stores the info on Linux.