# How to store Python application data

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, file-permissions, data-storage

I'm creating a simple Python CLI tool, which lets the user add and delete tasks (the classic Todo app). This is just for my own use, but I want to get into the best practices of creating such applications. The data will be stored in a simple text file.

**Main question**: Where should I store the data file? After doing [some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510104/where-to-store-application-data-non-user-specific-on-linux), I'm inclined to create a new folder in `/var/lib` and keep the `data.txt` file in that directory. Are there any drawbacks to that option?

**Follow up question**: Since, by default, only root has access to `/var`, do I need to change the permissions for the whole `/var` directory in order to read and write to the data file?

Comment: You can also try using the [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/1.2.0/) module.

Answer (score 6):

User data should be store in the user's home directory. You could use..

### Mac OS X

```
/Users/joe/.myclitool/data.txt
```

### GNU/Linux

```
/home/joe/.myclitool/data.txt
```

In Python this can be done with:

```
import os
import os.path

p = os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), ".myclitool", "data.txt")
```

Comment: I was just about to ask how the application would know the identity of the current user, but your edit clarified things. Thank you!