# How to set relative project path in XCode when target is /usr/local/bin

Tags: xcode

I can set my XCode project path for my Product to be relative and from that access other project relative paths. However, if I would like to install my Product to /usr/local/bin and still access project relative paths how do I do it?

My project layout is:

```
project/
-- Makefile
-- obj/
---- target .o files
-- python/
---- .py files
-- src/
---- C/C++ files incl headers
```

I want my Product to be at /usr/local/bin and also access my python folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is to set absolute paths to your project data files and refer to them from there. This path can then be hardcoded for your platform.

[Where to store application data (non-user specific) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510104/where-to-store-application-data-non-user-specific-on-linux)