# How to structure a python program to include configs?

Tags: python-3.x, config, networkx, directory-structure, pep8

I have a program which takes some data and generates a graphic, and some details of the graphic are unique to said graphic and are currently being stored in a manually created dictionary which is just read from at runtime. Is there a standard to which I can create more universal config files that aren't hacked together?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON (or YAML) file to store your configuration data. See also [Where to store application data (non-user specific) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510104/where-to-store-application-data-non-user-specific-on-linux) (contrary to title the article actually covers more than Linux).

Comment: You can use a plain python file to store data for importing. Why load and parse another file?

Comment: @OneCricketeer with json or the like is easier to modify at runtime

Comment: Python has a pickle library for object serialization @OneCricketeer but that is deprecated per documentation in favor of JSON.  In either case you end up with a dict, manipulate it as needed, and write it out again.

Comment: @Allan I wasn't referring to pickle, just a standard python file to import variables from. Most Flask/Django projects, for example have a config.py